# Worklight LDAP Authentication with more than 1 ldapProviderUrl URL

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst

We need to do a LDAP Authentication for login. It works fine for checking with a single AD server.

```
<loginModules>
    <loginModule name="LDAPLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule</className>
        <parameter name="ldapProviderUrl" value="${ldap.security.dom1.url}"/>
        <parameter name="ldapTimeoutMs" value="2000"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityAuthentication" value="simple"/>
        <parameter name="validationType" value="exists"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" value="{username}"/>

    </loginModule>
```

It works fine, if I use a single url in the ldapprovider URL. I wanted to add 2  ldap urls, one as primary & other as secondary. I tried adding comma ',' separated url's, where if the primary fails, it needs to check for the secondary url. the urls are configured in worklight.properties as below

```
ldap.security.dom1.url = LDAP://10.40.88.10/DC=10.40.88.10
ldap.security.dom2.url = LDAP://10.30.88.10/DC=10.30.88.10
```

The code is as below

```
<parameter name="ldapProviderUrl" value="${ldap.security.dom1.url},${ldap.security.dom2.url}"/>
```

But it throws the below error

```
LdapLoginModule authentication failed. Reason 'javax.naming.InvalidNameException: Invalid name: DC=10.30.28.10,LDAP://10.40.88.10/DC=10.40.88.10
at javax.naming.ldap.Rfc2253Parser.doParse(Rfc2253Parser.java:111)
at javax.naming.ldap.Rfc2253Parser.parseDn(Rfc2253Parser.java:74)
at javax.naming.ldap.LdapName.parse(LdapName.java:789)
at javax.naming.ldap.LdapName.<init>(LdapName.java:125)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNameParser.parse(LdapNameParser.java:39)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:299)
```

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [found here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-server/html/com/worklight/core/auth/ext/LdapLoginModule.html), `ldapProviderUrl` is expected to be a single, [RFC-2253](http://www.rfc-base.org/rfc-2253.html) parsable URL or IP address. You're receiving this error, because the module has no notion of a delimited "list" for this value.

Comment: Ok Noted. But how to achieve if there is a requirement of this type.